# Multiple group by and join statements in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a following query in raw SQL and I want to rewrite it using Django ORM.

```
 SELECT
      id,
      username,
      COALESCE(total, 0) as total,
      COALESCE(sum1, 0) as sum1,
      COALESCE(sum2, 0) as sum2,
      COALESCE(sum3, 0) as sum3,
      COALESCE(sum4, 0) as sum4,
      COALESCE(sum5, 0) as sum5
    FROM
      (SELECT
         s_id,
         SUM(am) AS total
       FROM S
       GROUP BY s_id
       ORDER BY total) AS total

      LEFT OUTER JOIN (

                        SELECT
                          s_id,
                          SUM(am) AS sum1
                        FROM submitted
                        WHERE category = ‘m’
                        GROUP BY s_id
                      ) AS sum1 USING (s_id)

      LEFT OUTER JOIN (

                        SELECT
                          s_id,
                          SUM(am) AS sum2
                        FROM submitted
                        WHERE category = ’s’
                        GROUP BY s_id
                      ) AS sum2 USING (s_id)
```

I can group by a table in Django using:

```
S.objects.values('s_id').annotate(total=Sum('am'))
```

The problem is I need somehow to join this result with the table S and then again and again. Is there a way to accomplish than using Django ORM?

Comment: May I ask why you are so keen to re-write it in the ORM?

Comment: @PhilipAdler mostly an interest. Though it also adds some flexibility